# unmapping in Vim

Tags: keyboard, vim, keyboard-layout, hotkeys, dvorak

I am in the habit of using both querty and dvorak keyboard mappings on my computer, and would like to make a function in **vim**, that remaps 
h to d, j to h, k to t, and l to n. I would also like a function that would switch the mappings back. I can handle the forward function, but am at a loss as to how I would unmap the previously defined mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim dvorak users may be interested in this wiki page that tells you how to use dvorak in insert mode while keeping the command keys the same in normal mode:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout

Also, the (i|n|x|etc.)unmap commands unmap.